# How to construct the network and account at client side

Tags: solidity, remix, android, browsers

I am doing a project which is related to the Ethereum. But I faced the problem, so I want to ask you something.

I’ll explain my project briefly. After a team meeting or purchase of materials, the application will be used to recognize receipts issued and deploy them in a block chain using Etherium's smart contract.
I use centOS10 server and maria database. I want to build a smart contract on a private network with browser solidity using the Remix platform.

We use the application to register the team and save it as a server. At this time, I would like to know whether it is possible to automatically create a user in the block chain every time a server is registered on the server, and if possible, please tell me a brief idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [web3.py latest version](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html?highlight=account#web3.account.Account.create) there is a method called `create` in `account` module.

```
w3.eth.account.create()
```

Returns:

- an object with private key and convenience methods

Example:

```
>>> from web3.auto import w3
>>> acct = w3.eth.account.create('KEYSMASH FJAFJKLDSKF7JKFDJ 1530')
>>> acct.address
'0x5ce9454909639D2D17A3F753ce7d93fa0b9aB12E'
>>> acct.privateKey
b"\xb2\\}\xb3\x1f\xee\xd9\x12''\xbf\t9\xdcv\x9a\x96VK-\xe4\xc4rm\x03[6\xec\xf1\xe5\xb3d"
```

---

In [JavaScript API web3.js v1.0](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=create#create) there is a method called `create` in `account` module.

```
web3.eth.accounts.create();
```

Returns:

Object - The account object with the following structure:

- `address` - string: The account address.
- `privateKey` - string: The accounts private key.
- `signTransaction(tx [, callback])` - Function: The function to sign
  transactions.
- `sign(data)` - Function: The function to sign transactions.

---

Example of returned object:

```
{
    address: "0xb8CE9ab6943e0eCED004cDe8e3bBed6568B2Fa01",
    privateKey: "0x348ce564d427a3311b6536bbcff9390d69395b06ed6c486954e971d960fe8709",
    signTransaction: function(tx){...},
    sign: function(data){...},
    encrypt: function(password){...}
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your comment :) I really appreciate.

But can I ask something more? I want to know how to make a private network in the same situation.

Comment: In Geth & tools there is a tool Puppeth. It helps to create custom genesis file. After genesis file created you will only have to find how to start a network from geth console. There are many good articles about that.

Comment: @HyunjiSong glad to help. As you are new to StackExchange sites please have a read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)